# Public SFTP server directory with no password or keyfile

Tags: ssh, password, sftp, ssh-keys

I want to be able to allow users to connect to my SFTP server under a restricted user that only has read access to view files in a certain directory that I upload to without it requiring a password or key-file for the user. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just expose the directory via HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't.  SFTP is based on the SSH protocol. And SSH requires either explicit credentials (username/password), key based login, or a Kerberos exchange.  The best you're likely going to do is have a username like 'anonymous' with a password that is the same and just make that known to your users.

Comment: couldn't null password option be specified in pam.d/ssh ? I once manage to specify an account as password less (not any passwordv alid, but session login wouldn't ask for a password for a specific uid).

Answer (score -1):

Or try different software. I am using SysaxAutomation. It comes with a script editor and can handle SFTP and so on.